# Неисправно работают роуты в контроллеах

Tags: yii2, url, маршрутизация, controller, hosting

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Для удобства контроллеры расположил в папке controllers/**admin**.
 На локальном OpenServer'е всё работало исправно. А при переезде на открытый хостинг ( REG.RU ) появились проблемы.

В Debug панеле rout'ы прописываются правильно, но почему-то не может найти файл view/index.php.

```
if (is_file($viewFile)) {
    $viewFile = FileHelper::localize($viewFile);
} else {
    throw new InvalidParamException("The view file does not exist: $viewFile");

}

$oldContext = $this->context;
```

[image: Не видит файл вида]

Вот так вот выглядят мои UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [

        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

    ],
],
```

В таком формате построено меню Nav::Widget

```
'items' => [
     ['label' => 'Просмотреть все', 'url' => ['/admin/lot']],
     '<li class="divider"></li>',
     '<li class="dropdown-header">Управление</li>',
     ['label' => 'Добавить лот', 'url' => ['/admin/lot/create']],
     ['label' => 'Описания лотов', 'url' => ['/admin/lotcomment']],
     ['label' => 'Свойства лотов', 'url' => ['/admin/lotproperty']],
     ['label' => 'Работа с изображениями', 'url' => ['/admin/img_upload']],
],
```

**Не могу понять в чём дело. Помогите пожалуйста**

Comment: Попробуйте в config/web.php добавить baseUrl. Найдите строку, где есть cookieValidationKey и снизу прям под ним пропишите 'baseUrl' => '',

Comment: Может есть смысл использовать модульную структуру, вместо вложенности папок? Так вы сможете разделить общие и админские контроллеры, вьюхи и модели

Comment: Огромное спасибо, baseUrl не помог.
Действительно, более правильным будет использовать в этих целях модуль.